# How do I create a content area (image gallery) that scrolls on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I was looking to create an image gallery in my blog. However, I was wondering how possible it would be for the gallery to scroll through my images on mouseOver. Basically, when the user moves his/her mouse up or down the image gallery, the images scroll up or down accordingly.

I have seen a few examples where it has been done in flash, but i was wondering if it was possible for it to be done in Javascript. An example of what I am talking about can be seen on [deep.co.uk](http://www.deep.co.uk). This example is constructed in flash and allows the user to skim through the agency's portfolio by moving the mouse up and down the div. I am aware that loads of free javascript alternatives are online, but i haven't managed to find anyone that does it on mouseOver. I would appreciate it if someone has come across something like this or has used something like this in one of their projects.

Thanks in advance.

Yours sincerely,
Seedorf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script which scrolls content **vertically** onMouseOver.

http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php

Answer (score 1):

Maaki has i nice version here:
http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/

supports mouse hot spot scrolling, and auto start/stop